# Attaching React functional components in compound pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React component using the compound pattern as follows:

```
import React from "react";

function Card({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function Heading({ children }) {
  return <h2>{children}</h2>;
}

export Heading;
export default Card;
```

I'm not sure why I cannot use the export as above. However when I do

```
Card.Heading = Heading;
export default Card;
```

I'm now able to consume as follows:

```
<Card>
  <Card.Heading>hello</Card.Heading>
</Card>
```

I am trying to find out why `Card.Heading = Heading` is working as expected. Is it valid to attach react components using dot[.] notation like how I did?

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is not working, because you didn't attach `Card` to `Heading` before exporting. An export don't attach them, in fact you would import them like so (I assume we are in a file called `Components.js`):

```
import Card {Heading} from "Components";
```

That has been said, because a component should be independent, you shouldn't be (even if it is valid, since functions are objects in JavaScript) attaching them like this for readability:

```
Card.Heading = Heading;
```

If you wanna consume different components as one with proprieties, you would  do something like this:

```
function Card({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function Heading({ children }) {
  return <h2>{children}</h2>;
}

export Heading;
export Card;
// or 
/*
export default {
  Heading
  Card
}*/
```

Then where you need those components, you do this:

```js
import * as Component from "Components" // for the first export
// import Component from "Components" // for the second one;

function App({ children }) {
  return(
  <Component.Card>
      <Component.Header />
      {children}
  
  </Component.Card>;)
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this is a valid pattern.

Since React components are functions and functions are first-class objects, it's valid to assign properties like you have done.  See the excerpt here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

As far as importing `Card` if you wanted to use `Card` in another file you'd need to do the following.

`import Card from './Card'` since it's the default export.

Alternatively you could change the export to looks something like this.

```
export default {
 Heading,
 Card
}
```

Comment: is this applicable to plain js as well, like if I define two function `add` & `subs` and later do something like `add.subs = add` ? I tried this as well but doesn't seem to work?

Comment: You could do this `add.subs()` after doing `add.subs = add`. It is like you are calling `add()`. I would suggest you to take a look at my answer that I just edited. I hope it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow function, this should fix your issue.

```js
import React from "react";

function Card({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

export const Heading = ({ children }) => {
  return <h2>{children}</h2>;
}

export default Card;
```

When importing from other file:

```
import Card, { Heading } from 'file emplacement';
```

Comment: Yeah sure I can do this, but why `Card.Heading` is working in this case?